# How to use VBA to pull out a list of quoted phrases from a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having some issues with my code - specifically trying to pull out phrases in quotation marks, and insert into a word document

For example, a word document with content

"XYZ" "XYZ" [ABC] [ABC]

The code does not work for quotation marks, but if I switch out the """" to "[" in the .Text line, and to "]" in the C.set value it will pull out ABC ABC as it recognises the square brackets.

Any ideas how to get VBA to recognise the quotation marks?

Thanks

```
Sub ExtractText()
    Dim cDoc As Word.Document, nDoc As Word.Document
    Dim cRng As Word.Range, nRng As Word.Range
    
    Set cDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set nDoc = Documents.Add
    
    Set cRng = cDoc.Content
    Set nRng = nDoc.Content
    
    cRng.Find.ClearFormatting
    With cRng.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Text = """"
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            cRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:="""", Count:=Word.wdForward
            
            nRng.FormattedText = cRng.FormattedText
            nRng.InsertParagraphAfter
            nRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
           cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: chr$(34)  is probably the most readable way to do it.

Comment: if you are not interested in formatting, using regex could be a solution which is also much faster

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
Sub ExtractText()
    Dim cDoc As Document, cRng As Range
    Dim nDoc As Document, nRng As Range
    
    Set cDoc = ActiveDocument: Set cRng = cDoc.Range
    Set nDoc = Documents.Add:  Set nRng = nDoc.Range
    
    With cDoc.Range
        With .Find
            .Forward = True
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "[""""“]*[”""""]"
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute = True
            With .Duplicate
                .Start = .Start + 1
                .End = .End - 1
                nRng.FormattedText = .FormattedText
                nRng.InsertParagraphAfter
                nRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End With
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code handles smart quotes also.

Comment: phenomonal - thank you!